# Changing json attributes order in python flask/marshmallow

Tags: python, flask, marshmallow

I'm using flask, sqlalchemy and marshmallow to write a simple REST API. By default the model is always serialized into a json with alphabetical ordered attributes.

**Is there a way to specify the order of the json attributes with marshmallow?**

For example:

```
class Sample(db.Model):
    y = db.Column(db.String(256), primary_key=True)
    x = db.Column(db.String(256))

    def __init__(self, y, x):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

class SampleSchema(Schema):
    y = fields.Str()
    x = fields.Str()

@app.route('/sample')
def get_sample():
    dummy = Sample("MyY", "MyX")
    logger.info(dummy)
    schema = SampleSchema()
    return jsonify(schema.dump(dummy).data)
```

returns

```
{
  "x": "MyX", 
  "y": "MyY"
}
```

but  I would expect

```
{
  "y": "MyY", 
  "x": "MyX"
}
```

I'm aware that json is an unordered set and it does not matter for the client. However, it's more for debug purpose during development and pretty printing. So I would expect a framework to let me define the order of the attributes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you can set `ordered = True` in the [Schema's Class Meta](http://marshmallow.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api_reference.html#marshmallow.Schema.Meta):

```
class SampleSchema(Schema):
    class Meta:
        ordered = True
```

The output will be ordered according to the order that the fields are defined in the class.